# Getting started with Prolog

Tags: scala, clojure, prolog, constraint-programming

i'm rephrasing my question as it is deemed too opinion based. I will try to be more specific this time.

I wish to learn programming languages to expand my way of thinking and expressing problems:

Here are some background. My purposes for learning specific languages.

- Scala as an OO-Functional hybrid for reactive programming
- Clojure as a Lisp dialect for experiencing the power of macros
- Note that Scala being statically typed and Clojure being dynamic is a bonus for me as i get to learn their pros and cons at the same time

What are the things to pay attention to in the process of learning Prolog that would help me think better?

So far, my research suggests that one of the most powerful feature of Prolog is its ease of implementing "Backtracking".

> previous Version:
>
> I figured I should learn prolog to add to my arsenal of programming.
>   But what is the essence of prolog? As in, what are the main features
>   and what should I expect to take away from the experience?
>
> It would be nice to compare to Scala and Clojure as they're my
>   language of choice at the moment. I'm learning Scala mainly for actor
>   model/reactive programming, and the OO and functional approaches seem
>   really powerful to me. I took up Clojure because I wanted to pick up a
>   Lisp dialect to experience the power of macros, and so far, Clojure
>   had the most momentum. So what extras would Prolog give me?
>
> Can I get those benefits/experience/features in Erlang since it's
>   syntax is derived from Prolog?
>
> Thanks for looking at my question. Hope to hear all those wonderful
>   answers.

Comment: Prolog is really different.  Because it's a logic programming language, and its power is in large part a consequence of its search rules (which don't exist in other languages), it's not clear to me that you'd get any extras except a broadened perspective of what it meant to solve a problem.  I have not really used anything I learned in Prolog in any other programming contexts, mostly because I couldn't if I wanted to (without embedding a Prolog interpreter).

Comment: The power of Prolog is (in my experience) that if you get the Prolog way of thinking, you can use its own processing model for AI programs straight without programming more algorithms, which saves time and space. However, as a learning experience I think functional languages work as well. Basically and theoretically logic programming is functional programming where the function gives you all possible answers instead of just one.

Comment: If you're already using Clojure, why not take a look into core.logic, Clojure's foray into logic programming ? It seems a lot of Prolog's principles and even syntax has found it's way into it.

Comment: adsisco, IMO no amount of editing is going to make this question a good fit for SO I'm afraid..

Comment: then its really disappointing, any idea where i can bring this question to?

Comment: @adsisco Maybe try 'Prolog Programming' on google plus, programmers.stackexchange.com, reddit.com/r/prolog/, or the ##prolog irc on freenode. Stackoverflow has a very narrow focus. Things to learn from Prolog: the Logical Programming paradigm (to compliment FP and OO); robust pattern matching + homoiconicity make it excel at meta-programming; look forward to working with constraint satisfaction; think about the purely logical relations in programs and problem spaces and why the procedural nature of computation requires the cut; forget about functions to learn to think in predicates.

Comment: The syntax has most certainly _not_ made it into core.logic.